# how can I draw a line with title in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

[This is design I received from designer but I cannot find a way to implement this in React](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyhSx.png)

Actually, I tried to use  with 1px Height, but cannot place text at the starting part of the line.

```
import React from 'react';

export const Separator: React.FunctionComponent<{title: string}> = ({ title }) => {
  const separatorStyle = {
    width: '100%',
    height: 1,
    marginBottom: 30,
    backgroundColor: '#EBEBEB'
  };

  return (
    <div style={separatorStyle}>
      {title}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Seem like you need to use <legend> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/legend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ever developed that kind of separator component, and it needs some css styles for the title.
Don't put that title directly inside .

```
const separatorTitleStyle = {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: 80,
    marginLeft: 30,
    top: '50%',
    transform: 'translateY(-50%)',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  };
```

```
<div style={separatorStyle}>
    <div style={separatorTitleStyle}>{title}</div>
</div>
```

You can change some css styles as you wish.

Comment: Used that in the code, and it worked perfectly. The only thing I changed is fontsize, width and most of them are correct, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .draw-line:before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        background-color: black;
        height: 1px;
        width: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
      }
      .draw-line:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        background-color: black;
        height: 1px;
        flex-grow: 1;
        margin-left: 10px;
      }
      .draw-line {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="draw-line">Title</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I think you can convert this code to React component. ;)